# php regular expression to parse port data

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
$teststring = " 

                                         Flow Link          Back   Mdix
```

Port     Type         Duplex  Speed Neg      ctrl State       Pressure Mode

---

fa1      100M-Copper    --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
fa2      100M-Copper    --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
fa3      100M-Copper    --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
fa4      100M-Copper    --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
fa5      100M-Copper    --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
fa6      100M-Copper    --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
fa7      100M-Copper    --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
fa8      100M-Copper    --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
gi1      1G-Combo-C     --      --     --     --  Down           --     --
gi2      1G-Combo-C   Full    100   Enabled  Off  Up          Disabled Off

```
                                      Flow    Link
```

Ch       Type    Duplex  Speed  Neg      control  State

---

Po1         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present 
Po2         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present 
Po3         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present 
Po4         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present 
Po5         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present 
Po6         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present 
Po7         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present 
Po8         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present "
;

I'm trying to parse each field.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
$teststring = explode("<BR>", $teststring);     
$vlandetailsArray = array();
foreach ($teststring as $vlandetails) 
{            
  //              port     space    type     space   duplex          speed       space  neg         
  $pattern = '/([a-z0-9]*)(\s*)([a-z0-9\-]*)(\s*)[(Full)|(\-{2})](\s*)[(\-)+|(100)](\s*)[(--)*|(Enabled)](\s*)[(--)*|(Off)]/i';

  if (preg_match($pattern, $vlandetails, $matches)) 
  {  
       echo 'match 0: '.$matches[0].'<br>';  //0 index always returns all matches
      }
```

This returns the following:

```
match 0: -------- ---- 
match 0: fa1 100M-Copper -- -- 
match 0: fa2 100M-Copper -- -- 
match 0: fa3 100M-Copper -- -- 
match 0: fa4 100M-Copper -- -- 
match 0: fa5 100M-Copper -- -- 
match 0: fa6 100M-Copper -- -- 
match 0: fa7 100M-Copper -- -- 
match 0: fa8 100M-Copper -- -- 
match 0: gi1 1G-Combo-C -- -- 
match 0: -------- ----
match 0: Po1 -- -- -- 
match 0: Po2 -- -- -- 
match 0: Po3 -- -- --
match 0: Po4 -- -- -- 
match 0: Po5 -- -- -- 
match 0: Po6 -- -- --
match 0: Po7 -- -- -- 
match 0: Po8 -- -- --
```

I don't understand why it's not picking up the line that looks like this:

```
gi2      1G-Combo-C   Full    100   Enabled  Off  Up          Disabled Off
```

Can you tell me what i'm missing / doing wrong?
FYI.  I'm still playing around with my regex,so you'll notice that sometimes i use the pattern (-{2}) and other times -+ etc.

**EDIT 1**

I've modified the teststring.  Previously, I had the following code to replace any CR LF with 
.

```
        $this->_data  = str_replace(chr(10),"<BR>",$this->_data ,$count);//strip New line
        $this->_data  = str_replace(chr(13),'',$this->_data ,$count);//strip carriage return
```

I'm sorry, I overlooked these lines of code - have too many "tests" in my page.  The test string you see now is the "raw" stuff.  I just save everything to a file like so:

```
 $fp = fopen('/var/www/lsm/application/logs/showinterfacesstatus.txt', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, $this->_data);
 fclose($fp);
```

where $this->_data contains the raw data.   i opened this file and copied everything ... then pasted into my teststring variable.
Having said that, I have analyzed the file in a text editor and i can see that the only thing that's different between the original string and the modified string is that it has been stripped of all CRLFs.  But in case it helps, I've removed this logic.
I've also included a screenshot of the unmodified data inside a text editor.
thanks. 
[image: originaldata]

Comment: This sure looks like only spaces allowed as delimeters. Are theese spaces or `\t`-s? You could use simple `str_split` line-by-line and then space-by-space instead of regular expressions. Just figure the way they separate the data.

Comment: @Ranty \s should pick up tab characters too, unless there is something specific to php RegEx's I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#[a-z]{2}\d\s[^\s]+ [a-z\-]+[^\s]+ ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+)#si
```

You must have case-insensitive mode enabled.

Other one, to capture the... inteface name?

```
#[a-z]{2}\d ([^\s]+) [a-z\-]+[^\s]+ ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+)#si
```

Full code example:

```
<?php

$teststring = " 
Flow Link Back Mdix 
Port Type Duplex Speed Neg ctrl State Pressure Mode 
-------- ------------ ------ ----- -------- ---- ----------- -------- ------- 
fa1 100M-Copper -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
fa2 100M-Copper -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
fa3 100M-Copper -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
fa4 100M-Copper -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
fa5 100M-Copper -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
fa6 100M-Copper -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
fa7 100M-Copper -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
fa8 100M-Copper -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
gi1 1G-Combo-C -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
gi2 1G-Combo-C Full 100 Enabled Off Up Disabled Off 

Flow Link 
Ch Type Duplex Speed Neg control State 
-------- ------- ------ ----- -------- ------- ----------- 
Po1 -- -- -- -- -- Not Present 
Po2 -- -- -- -- -- Not Present 
Po3 -- -- -- -- -- Not Present 
Po4 -- -- -- -- -- Not Present 
Po5 -- -- -- -- -- Not Present 
Po6 -- -- -- -- -- Not Present 
Po7 -- -- -- -- -- Not Present 
Po8 -- -- -- -- -- Not Present";

$pattern = '#[a-z]{2}\d ([^\s]+) [a-z\-]+[^\s]+ ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+)#si';

preg_match_all($pattern, $teststring, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($match);
    echo '</pre>';
}

/* EOF */
```

Comment: There I updated the answer with a full code example. It works with the text of your question. I avoided the ''explode('<BR>')'' stuff since there aren't any html break lines in the original string.

Comment: Diego, I've updated my post.  YOur comment about ignoring <BR> triggered my memory that I am / was replacing CRLF with <BR>.  It doesn't appear too cleanly in this post because the CRLFs that are embedded in it.

Comment: Anyways if after cleaning up the string you can get it with the same format as your first example (wich, by the way, it looks broken now after your last edit) to the preg_match_all line, the example should work as expected. If it worked don't forget to accept the answer!.

Answer (score 0):

here's the regex pattern that works:

$pattern = '/([a-z]{2}\d)(\s*)([0-9a-z-]*)(\s*)([a-z-]*)(\s*)([0-9-]*)(\s*)([a-z-]*)(\s*)([a-z-]*)(\s*)([a-z-]*)(\s*)([a-z-]*)(\s*)([a-z-]*)/i';